# Spring Cloud Stream - Is there a way to customize the StreamThread thread name?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

I'm using Spring Cloud Stream (Kafka as the binder) in my current project and the default thread name for `StreamThread` keeps me bothered as it is very long.

Here's what it looks like:

```
<applicationId>-<GUID>-StreamThread-1
someEvent-578fb764-3fba-4a54-9a34-ea9796053530-StreamThread-1
```

With this long thread name, it is hard to see the actual log message.

Would like to know if there's a way to configure the thread name.

I already tried the one below but it is not working:

```
@Bean
public ListenerContainerCustomizer<AbstractMessageListenerContainer<?, ?>> listenerCustomizer() {
    return (container, destinationName, group) -> {
        // Format to "[group].[destination]
        container.setBeanName(String.format("%s.%s", group, destinationName));
    };
}
```

Maybe I'm in the wrong config?

Side note: I enjoy using Spring Cloud Stream, and it is quite popular from what I see. But it keeps me wondering why I can't get any good documentation.

Edit:
Solved the issue by adding `spring.kafka.client-id` in `application.properties`.

Having the `client-id` present, `KafkaStreams` will use the user-defined `client-id` as the thread name.

Comment: Those threads are created by `kafka-streams` and have nothing to do with Spring.

Comment: Hi @GaryRussell, I've used `spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-streams` as the binder, so it does manage by Spring. But it is also possible that you're right. But in any case, just wanted to look for a way to customize the thread name, Spring or Kafka approach.

Comment: When you say "I can't get any good documentation", what exactly do you mean by this? We have reference documentation - https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/3.2.2/reference/html/ and if you believe there is something missing please be a bit more specific so we can update or even better; raise an issue https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues

Comment: Hello @GaryRussell, thanks for giving me insight about Spring and `kafka-streams`. It turns out there's a separate config for Kafka-related config which is outside the Spring Cloud Stream, and `clientId` is one of them.

Comment: @OlegZhurakousky, thanks for this link! I'll add whenever I stumbled again into some issue where I cannot find any documentation. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that you use plain Kafka binder, but not Kafka Streams binder? That `StreamThread` gets its name like `final String threadId = clientId + "-StreamThread-" + threadIdx;`. See `StreamThread` source code. So, you need to be sure what is that `clientId` propagated down to Kafka Streams.

See `StreamsConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG` which you can configure via `spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder.applicationId` property.

**UPDATE**

OK. I found the logic in the `KafkaStreams`:

```
    // The application ID is a required config and hence should always have value
    final String userClientId = config.getString(StreamsConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG);
    final String applicationId = config.getString(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG);
    if (userClientId.length() <= 0) {
        clientId = applicationId + "-" + processId;
    } else {
        clientId = userClientId;
    }
   ...
   final String baseName = clientId + "-StreamThread-";
```

So, the final thread name is based on that `clientId` exactly.

If that `StreamsConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG` is empty, then it is based on the `applicationId` plus that `processId`. which might be indeed a GUID  you mention.

Therefore consider to set that `StreamsConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG` instead of an `applicationId`.

Comment: Hi Artem, apologies for my post for being bland. I've used `Kafka Streams` (artifactId: `spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-streams`) for my Stream Cloud stream binder. Just wanted to know if I can customize the thread name to shorten it as it is very long. I can actually see the `applicationId`, but it was followed by GUID which causes long thread name. Is it possible to remove that?

Comment: Please, see an UPDATE in my answer.

Comment: Thanks, Artem for your suggestion! I was now able to shorten the thread name by specifying the `clientId`.